# change path of roscd

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials of the ros man page. I have a query. Whenever I use `roscd beginner_tutorials` I get:

```
/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials$
```

How can I change roscd so that it gives me the path of beginner_tutorials in the `/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials folder`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64772/change-path-of-roscd/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is directly related to a problem you are trying to solve in your previous [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/64763/change-path-of-rosrun-couldnt-find-executables/).

Make sure you are familiar with [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace).

In short, there are *install space* and *development space*. If you source `devel/setup.bash` then `roscd beginner_tutorials` should bring you to `~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials`. But if you source `install/setup.bash` then it will bring you to the directory where the package was installed.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2